# Jinja code rendered using Flask not appearing in html when viewing page source

Tags: html, flask, jinja2

I am creating a simple web app using flask, html and css. However, the data from my form does not get submitted to my SQLite database, and also doesn't appear in my html table. When I view page source I notice that the jinja code is actually missing.

```html
          <table class="table table-striped mt-5">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Title</th>
              <th>Author</th>
              <th>Category</th>
              <th>Read</th>
              <th></th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
             {% for book in booklist %}
             <tr>
               <td>{{book.title}}</td>
               <td>{{book.author}}</td>
               <td>{{book.category}}</td>
               <td>{{book.read}}</td>
             </tr>
             {% endfor %}
          </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say the value of `booklist` is [<Book_1>], the generated rows look like this

```
             <tr>
               <td>The Great Lake</td>
               <td>O. Thor</td>
               <td>mystery</td>
               <td>True</td>
             </tr>
```

but since `booklist` is empty, jinja iterates over an empty list and thus outputs

Comment: Ok, so how do I get it to iterate over the contents submitted from the html form?

Comment: You need to give us your Flask code

Comment: I found the problem. My flask code had an issue with the if statement. Problem is now resolved. Thanks for your help!